# Общее придаточное или нет?

Tags: запятые, придаточное-предложение

Теперь же, когда они улеглись в словесное изложение, я уже не властен над ними(,) и они перестали быть моими.

Правильно ли я рассуждаю? Если автор считает предложения однородными, то есть с общим придаточным, то запятую не ставит. А если считает, что последнее предложение независимо (или вытекает из всей первой части), то ставит.

Comment: А здесь не придаточное может быть общим, а "теперь же". А придаточное уточняет его.

Comment: @oleedd Ну да, они заодно.

Comment: @Kirill А не могли бы вы пояснить немного предложение? Я вообще не понимаю, что значит ‟улеглись в словесное изложение”. Кто над кем не властен? Кто перестал быть чьими? Это что-то из типично-аморфных рассуждений писателей о том, что написав произведение, автор перестает быть властен над ним?

Comment: @oleedd  Текст до этого: "Я выбрал форму литературного изложения, в которой стал одновременно и учеником, и передатчиком своих внутренних открытий и озарений. Пока я доставал их из себя и словесно оформлял в поток состояний и образов, я мог считать их своими".

Comment: А почему, оформляя в поток состояний и образов, он мог считать их своими, а сформулировав на бумаге, он потерял над ними власть и они перестали быть его? Люди из области литературоведения – дикий народ, и их очень трудно понимать.

Comment: @oleedd Ну вот так, я сам не в восторге... Друзья-знакомые попросили вычитать, считая меня грамотным. )

Comment: @Kirill Вам уже другой человек пишет)

Comment: Извините, не обратил внимания.

Comment: Здесь, по ходу, с "когда" разговорный (хаковый) вариант. А академические: *Теперь же, когда они уложены в словесное изложение. Теперь же, после того как они улеглись в словесное изложение.* А то искал-искал такое в словарях, и ничего подобного нет.

Comment: @oleedd  А чем отличается "когда они уложены" от "когда они улеглись"? Пассивной и активной формой?

Comment: Дело в том, что "теперь" — это настоящее, а "улеглись" — прошедшее. С причастием тоже настоящее (*когда они являются таковыми*).

Comment: @oleedd Да, понимаю, хотя с формальной точки зрения "уложен" - причастие прошедшего времени. Это типа как "я опоздал", "я являюсь опоздавшим" в англ. выражается настоящим "I am late".

Comment: Причастие прошедшего времени, но действие в настоящем: *когда они есть уложены*.

Comment: По ходу, в разговорной речи заменяют "после того как" на "когда", но в словарях ничего подобного нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Теперь же, **когда они улеглись в словесное изложение**, я уже не властен над ними, и они перестали быть моими.*

Рассуждаете вы верно, вот только в данном предложении независимость или зависимость двух событий во втором и третьем предложении **не проявлена однозначно.** Можно прийти к любому выводу, поэтому нет смысла на это ориентироваться.

Более важно то, что распространенность предложений и повтор местоимения (над ними, они) **препятствуют** их объединению.

Поэтому мы считаем предложения **независимыми** и ставим запятую (делаем паузу) перед союзом И.  Придаточное не является общим.

Comment: Важно: если по смыслу потенциальный общий элемент является общим, но части слишком неоднородные, то правильный выход — не ставить запятую, а перестроить предложение, чтобы было пооднороднее. Это вам в общем. Это касается предложения "Будем надеяться, повезёт и разбогатею". А то иногда запятая нарушает смысл (так в примере с "разбогатею").

Answer (score 1):

Сперва следует сказать, что это предложение из области литературоведения и его трудно отчётливо понять, даже зная контекст, потому что люди из области литературоведения – совершенно дикие.
Прочитав предложения перед этим предложением можно сделать такой вывод: у автора были какие-то идеи, пока эти идеи были в виде потока состояний и образов, эти идеи принадлежали автору и он был властен над ними, а когда он сформулировал их на бумаге, то перестал быть властен над ними и они перестали ему принадлежать. (Шиза, но какая-то логика прослеживается, если напрячься.) Вроде как это одно и то же, когда тебе что-то принадлежит и когда ты властен на чем-то, но предположим, что это не так.  Оба предложения определённо относятся к сочетанию ‟тогда же” – после изложения на бумаге они перестали быть моими и я потерял над ними власть. Запятую ставить нельзя по правилу об отсутствии запятой при отношении сложносочинённых к общему сочетанию.

Во втором предложении подлежащее является личным местоимением, но запятая в таком случае ставится вопреки отношению обоих предложений к общему сочетанию, если это личное местоимение обозначает то же, что и подлежащее первого предложения, а здесь подлежащее первого предложения обозначает автора, а подлежащее второго предложения (личное местоимение) обозначает идеи. Так что этот пункт не подходит. [Вот этот пункт правила в справочнике Розенталя (примечание к первому подпункту первого пункта).](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

И ещё, запятая в такой ситуации не является интонационной, это можно доказать следующим образом: можно взять предложение, в котором есть запятая, как предложение: ‟Никита ударил Василия, и Василий упал”, а потом добавить общий элемент, и интонация не изменится, но запятая исчезнет: ‟Я видел, как Никита ударил Василия и Василий упал”. Эта запятая выполняет функцию отнесения или не отнесения предложений к общему сочетанию.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146301/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Видите, вы колеблетесь насчёт запятой в первом предложении. А в таких случаях очень помогает анализ интонации (произношения). Если вам не помогает, то вы не умеете. Хотя здесь только один вариант.

Comment: Я не колеблюсь, я на секунду подумал, что там местоимение является подлежащим, и оно обозначает то же, что и подлежащее в первом предложении.

Comment: Вы несколько раз исправляли.

Comment: Нет, я исправил, а потом сразу же исправил назад.

Comment: *Шиза, но какая-то логика прослеживается, если напрячься* — вот, вы ленитесь напрягаться, и у вас везде шиза.

Comment: Здесь очень много нюансов. Вы стилистику не учитываете. Ещё надо анализировать, удачно ли объединение. А на это влияет и длина, и то, как читается, и однородность (особенно, на это многое влияет). Например, в следующем предложении не подходит объединение: *Сегодня сделаю уроки, и мы пойдём гулять после этого.*

Comment: Жалко, тогда ответите по возвращении. Просто вы матюк употребили, думаю, из-за этого.